How to create a live voice activity detection (VAD) loop for whisperX?
I am using whisperX speech-to-text model to convert my voice into text input for a locally hosted LLM.
Right now, I have it set up where I can record an audio file, and then load it into whisperX. I am very satisfied with the speed/quality, and can accurately transcribe an entire movie's worth of speech in less than a minute.
But what I would like to do instead of using pre-recorded audio files, is have the microphone always on/listening and use voice activity detection (VAD) to detect when I start/stop speaking and then process the voice --> text. I have read through whisperX's VAD source code in whisperx/vad.py but cannot understand how to properly integrate this into a live loop that converts speech-->text in real time.
Can someone show me some example code of what this would look like to process a live audio stream instead of a fixed-length audio file, or point me to an open source project that has this sort of live audio input loop using whisperX?
Thanks!

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

I am asking how to transcribe a live audio stream with whisperX instead of a pre-recorded audio file.
